# How to extract list of unique combinations from multiline array, where only every two consecutive rows are the basis for combinations?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, unique, combinations

From a multiline table I'm trying to extract (and count) all unique combinations between every two rows.

[image: Example with desired result]

I have found a way by creating intermediate tables: 1) I use JOIN to create the combinations between each "city" and "zone" row. 2) I rearrange the result into one single column (as necessary for the following UNIQUE function) by entering a TRANSPOSE function every 7th row (because there are 7 columns). 3) I then use UNIQUE and COUNTIF in a third table for the final result.

Link to the example with data and desired result on first sheet, and my solution on the second sheet: [Google Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19WCQoikL8NSKE_IaTrCiKt7ww4d0wru4YSpvqOjgz0g/edit?usp=sharing)

As my final sheet will be rather large (~2000 rows, 40 columns, ~4000 unique combinations expected), my main problem with my own solution is the manual step to rearrange the city/zone combinations into one single column as preparation for the UNIQUE function.

Is there a way to achieve the same final result without the intermediate steps from my solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C11:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY( TRANSPOSE( QUERY("☯"&QUERY(TO_TEXT(B1:H8),"skipping 2",0)&" "&QUERY(B2:H8,"skipping 2",0),,2^99)),,2^99),"☯"))," Select Col1, count(Col1) group by Col1",0))
```

- Create two arrays with query's skipping,  one containing cites and other containing zones
- JOIN those arrays with a delimiter using Query headers
- SPLIT and TRANSPOSE to create a single column
- QUERY to create a frequency count.

Comment: Thanks, this works, except for the 50k limit on TEXTJOIN. Following the link in your answer, I set the header count in all three queries to 9^99. But I still get a 50k limitation error from TEXTJOIN.

Comment: @Morphan Edited to remove limits